# Check title of multiple pages in Selenium

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, automated-tests

I'm currently using WebDriver.js to run some automated testing on Browserstack. My goal is to take all the hrefs in a given div, open them and check the title of the page where the link is pointing to. To do that I'm doing the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
    var href = hrefs[i],
        site_name = sites_names[i];

    driver.get(href);
    driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
        assert.equal(title, site_name);
    });
}
```

My problem is that `get` and `getTitle` are both asynchronous methods and thus when I'm calling `getTitle` the page is already changed and thus the assertion is failing. What is the best pattern/solution for this kind of sitations?

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question correctly, your assertions are failing because the assert happens before the page is completely loaded in the browser? I think you require a "wait" logic around your `getTitle` call as [mentioned here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs)

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(function() {
 return driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
   return title === 'webdriver - Google Search';
 });
}, 1000);

driver.quit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is not exactly that. Let me explain it better: suppose I have 2 arrays one with the hrefs ['google.com', ..., 'foobaz.bar'] and one with the expected titles ['Google', ... 'Foo Bar Inc.']. My problem is that `get` and `getTitle` are not synchronised and thus I end up with the foobaz.bar page loaded and the check for the title of 'Google'.

Comment: use list or any collections over array

Comment: @MarcelloRomanelli As an example, if hrefs[0]='google.com' and site_names[0]='Google' then the only possible way the assert will fail if the test is not waiting long enough for the page to load before validating the title. As mentioned earlier, wrapping the driver.getTitle() call in a wait should resolve the problem.

Comment: @shri046 the assert is failing because the loop is incrementing even though the promise returned by the getTitle is not in a successful status yet.

Comment: @MarcelloRomanelli And that is exactly where you need the wait method wrapped around the assert so that you are not asserting the title before the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just check the title of all the links present in you page you can change your driver to

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```

This is just a good practice.... not mandatory (to increase the speed of execution). After checking the title you can change your driver back to the original. 
Use the below code to iterate valid href one by one and assert it accordingly

```
    List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")); // use tagname according to the need

    for (WebElement link : allLinks) {
    if (link.getAttribute("href") != null && link.getText().isEmpty()==false) { //again modify the condition here accordingly
        driver.get(link.getAttribute("href"));
        driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
             assert.equal(title, site_name);
        });         
    }
    }
```